# .NET Core - ExecuteSqlRaw - last inserted id?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core

This seems silly, but I cannot find any example code that shows how to retrieve the last inserted `id` when doing an insert query with `ExecuteSqlRaw`

```
var sql = @"INSERT INTO [MyDb-Dev].[dbo].[" + table + "] (...) VALUES (...)";
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql);
```

How do I retrieve the last inserted `id` ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this with an output parameter. Have a look at this link: https://www.yogihosting.com/stored-procedures-entity-framework-core/

Comment: but how do you get the id of the inserted record to be stored in the output parameter?

Answer (score 1):

add this to the query

```
;SELECT @LastCreatedId = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
```

add a parameter to the call

```
var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@LastCreatedId", SqlDbType.Int);
returnCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

get the value like this

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql3, parameters);
returnValue = (int)returnCode.Value;
```

Comment: This works only if there is property in table with identity on it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get inserted id with `OUTPUT` in MS SQL Server.

> OUTPUT returns information from, or expressions based on, each row affected
> by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. These results can be
> returned to the processing application for use in such things as
> confirmation messages, archiving, and other such application
> requirements.

```csh
var sql = @"INSERT INTO [MyDb-Dev].[dbo].[" + table + "] (...) OUTPUT inserted.Id VALUES (...)";
int returnValue = _context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it does not work, I insert a record, forcing the Id, it should be 23 (the id in db too), the return value is 1

Comment: it does so for all inserted records

Comment: I tried using ExecuteSqlCommand, same issue, while testing a dummy query in SQL returns the correct value...is there a bug somewhere in the API?

Comment: @phil123456 I have updated my answer, instead of ExecuteSqlCommand you can use SqlQuery and cast value into int.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, with c# .net core 6.0

```
var output = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@InsertedId",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
string sqlRaw = @" 
                    INSERT INTO tableName(field1, field2, field3, field4)
                    values({0}, {1}, {2}, {3});
                    SELECT @InsertedId = @@IDENTITY;";
    await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sqlRaw, var0, var1, var2, var3,output);
    int insertedId = Convert.ToInt32(output.Value);
```

The await and ExecuteSqlRawAsync is for performance, but you can change that line like this instead:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sqlRaw, var0, var1, var2, var3,output);
```

Hope it helps someone.
Regards.